# Can't Build .Net Maui Android apk or aab file using Visual Studio Enterprise

Tags: xamarin.android, apk, maui, android-app-bundle

I'm following these instructions.
https://www.telerik.com/blogs/publishing-dotnet-maui-app-android

The Build process creates the dll and pdb file, but not the apk or aab files. I'm running Microsoft Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.4.3.

My keystore is here.

C:\Users\myname\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android

Here is my code.

```
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(TargetFramework)|$(Platform)'=='Release|net7.0-android33.0|AnyCPU'">
    <AndroidKeyStore>True</AndroidKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyStore>..\..\..\AppData\Local\Xamarin\Mono for Android\MyApp.keystore</AndroidSigningKeyStore>
    <AndroidSigningKeyAlias>MyAlias</AndroidSigningKeyAlias>
    <AndroidSigningKeyPass>MyPassword</AndroidSigningKeyPass>
    <AndroidSigningStorePass>MyPassword</AndroidSigningStorePass>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

I'm not getting an error message. Not sure what the problem is.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you checked the official document about [publish a .NET MAUI app for Android with the CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/deployment/publish-cli?view=net-maui-7.0)?

Comment: I will try this. Do I have the production keystore in the correct folder? I simply put it where the dubug keystore was located.

Answer (score 2):

@LiyunZhang-MSFT It worked! All I had to do is run this line in View - Terminal.

```
dotnet publish -f:net7.0-android -c:Release /p:AndroidSigningKeyPass=mypassword /p:AndroidSigningStorePass=mypassword
```

I changed this line for Android 33.

```
-f:net7.0-android33.0
```

The apk and aab files are located here.

```
bin\Release\net7.0-android33.0
```

Comment: Thanks. But, why doesn't the Visual Studio generate the APK rather than opening a terminal and running a command?